# Download Document in browsers using Jquery supporting browsers IE , Safari and FireFox

Tags: jquery, json

```
Able to save JSON content as document and display download details at the   bottom bar in Chrome.     
using $window.open(url'_blank') for other browsers , so it opens as new   tab/window.
Any help at the earliest would be great.
```

Code works for chrome: 
    found the below link to save document  sample of jquery function

```
           $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../Document/DownloadDocument?DocumentID=123456',
                  data:$("#generateDocument").serialize),                                             
                    success: function (DocFilePath) {                           
                        var link = document.createElement('a');                           
                        link.download = Filename + "_profile" + type;                            
                        link.onclick = downloadDoc(DocFilePath) ;
                        window.location.href = redirecturl;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                           
                        alert("Error" + thrownError);
                    }
                });
       function downloadDoc(url) {
       window.location = url;
       }
```

Comment: you want to download document without opening another tab?

Comment: yeah....I can do that in chrome .but the same doesn't work for other browsers

Comment: you have multiple anchor tag?

Comment: no...just the one which is created in jquery

Comment: add `link.onclick = downloadDoc(url);` and create a method with `function downloadDoc(url){ window.location = url; }`

Comment: why you use this `window.location.href = redirecturl;`

Comment: window.location.href = redirecturl; i want to redirect my page from report generated page. so just menioned n that way

Comment: can u come on conversation

Answer (score 0):

In controller create Two action result one for processing and another to download file only.

```
    public ActionResult DocumentProcess(string documentId)
    {
        //do your stuff what ever processing is..
        //Create a filePath which you have to download.
        string filePath = @"F:\umair\Documents\BioVeriSys-Interface Document.pdf";


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentId) ) //proccessing success then return with success and full filePath.
        return Json(new { success = 1, message = "Document processing Successfully Completed", filePath = filePath }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json(new { success = 0, message = "documentId is required but its empy or null."}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
        if (file.Exists)
            return File(file.FullName, "application/pdf", file.Name +".pdf");
        else
            return HttpNotFound();
    }
```

And in **View**

for testing purpos i created two buttons one for documentId and another for without documentId.

```
<button onclick="myfunction(123)"> With documentId  </button>
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="myfunction('')"> Without doucemntId </button>

@section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction(documentId) {

            $.post('@Url.Action("DocumentProcess","Home")?documentId=' + documentId,
                { /*$("#generateDocument").serialize)*/ },
                function (data) {
                    if (data.success > 0) {// mean server return with success message.
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Home")?fileName=' + data.filePath;
                    } else { // means some validation not true
                        alert(data.message);    
                    }
                }
                ).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ':' + errorThrown);
                });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137844/discussion-on-answer-by-umair-anwaar-download-document-in-browsers-using-jquery).